# How to auto increment index for my dynamically generated html code

Tags: javascript, html

I have a java code which generates html code during run time.Basically I have whole html template stored as string in one variable , just row values are appended dynamically in variable to complete html file.After execution completed I open html report I get report like below:
[image]

The problem is I want Indx row to increment automatically as 1,2,3,4...as I open html report.

```
    <html>
     <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
       <h1 align="center">XYZ</h1>
        <style type='text/css'>
        .logTable {font-size:12px;color:#333333;width:100%;border-width: 
          1px;border-color: 
        #729ea5;border-collapse: collapse;}.logTable th {font- 
         size:12px;background-color:#730ea5;border- 
         width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border- 
          color:#730ea5;text-align:left;}.logTable 
           tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color:#00FF00;}.logTable tr:nth- 
         child(even) {background- 
         color:#ffffff;}.logTable td {font-size:12px;border-width: 
          1px;padding: 8px;border-style: 
         solid;border-color: #00FF00;}.logTable tr:hover {background- 
            color:#5cb3c4;}.txtColor 
         {color:red;}.warningText {color:yellow;}
     </style>
     </head>

    <body>
     <table class='logTable' border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Indx</th>
        <th>Scrsht</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Fle</th>
        <th>Level</th>
        <th>Msg</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>scremn</td>
        <td>"5r7date"</td>
        <td>"hjbk"</td>
        <td>"ajkb"</td>
        <td>ffhc</td>
    </tr>
      </body>
    </html>

    --------------------- Adding code below as asked by sunil lama
   public synchronized void Info(String message,boolean Flag) {
     try {
        String nameClass = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() 
        [2].getClassName();
        String nameMethod = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() 
        [2].getMethodName();
        String lineNumber = 
         Integer.toString(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() 
        [2].getLineNumber());
        String stack = "ClassName:-"+nameClass+" , MethodName:- 
          >"+nameMethod+" , LineNumber:->"+lineNumber;
        writer.append(getHtml(message,stack,Flag,driver,"INFO")); 
        writer.flush();
        i++;
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }

       can some one check the issue
```

Comment: your html is static, where is the code that is actually filling up your html dynamically?

Comment: @SunilLama I have a java project which just appends/inserts <tr>....</tr> in this html file

Comment: yes, please paste the part or function with which you are doing that

Comment: So you want this cell to increment each time you open this html page? You'll have to store it somewhere (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage may help if you want to store it locally in the browser).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question only asks for the code for the desired output. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: @SunilLama Added!!

Comment: There is no javascript in here